# Error handling on $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `GET` request using the `$http` service. However, the error handling is not executed.

This is the error I am getting, where I expect the console to print *"You are not logged in"*. (The API will respond with a *401* if the check fails)

[image: error message]

Here's the Angular code

```
$http.get($rootScope.api + '/authentication/check-login').then(function(response) {
    console.log('You are logged in');
}, function(response) {
    console.log('You are not logged in');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The request will still return 401 and log in the console, because it is an error as far as the browser is concerned. You could return from your server a 200 OK response, but include the 401 status code (to be read and interpreted by your app)

Comment: @JonathonBlok that does not make any sense... there's nothing wrong with a webservice returning a 401 and a response cannot have 2 status codes...

Comment: I thought you were concerned with the error log in the console and suggested returning the status code as part of the body of the response, not the status. I know you can only have one status.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.error`.

```
$http.get($rootScope.api + '/authentication/check-login')
.success(function(response) {
    console.log('You are logged in');
})
.error(function(response) {
    console.log('You are not logged in');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this--

```
$http.get($rootScope.api + '/authentication/check-login').success(function(data) {
        console.log('You are logged in');
      }).
      error(function(response) {
        console.log('You are not logged in');
      });
```

Source doc for more info- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http